# Ошибка присвоения list error

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Собственно на этапе реализации проекта возник эксепшн подобного рода:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Код такой:

```
response = session_api.users.get(user_ids=event.obj.peer_id, fields='sex')
print(response)

sex = response['sex']
```

Вывод в консоль такой:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> [{'id': 123, 'first_name': '123', 'last_name': '123', 'is_closed': False, 'can_access_closed': True, 'sex': 2}]

Что нужно: Достать из респонса ключ 'sex'. Я попытался обработать его, как обычный ассоциативный массив, но, к сожалению, выходит не все так просто.

Comment: Заранее простите За такой поганый код в сообщение(я тут впервые) 
Скину все на пастбин
Код: https://pastebin.com/p2602LXH
Вывод с print(response) : https://pastebin.com/VKsPGkH9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть внимательно, то можно увидеть, что `response` - словарь, вложенный в список. Поэтом сначла нужно обратиться к нужному элементу списка `response[0]`, а потом уже брать из него ключ:

```
sex = response[0]['sex']
```

А ошибка возникает из-за того, что индекс словаря не может быть строкой, а должен быть числом (о чем и говорит текст ошибки).

Comment: Черт, а я писал sex = response['sex'][0]
Дружище спасибо огромное за оперативный ответ, + 100 к карме)